# Review tools: how to configure preferences permanently?

Tags: bug, review, usability

While I can configure the preferences like (for instance)

- disable random showing of posts to review
- sort by newest first
- (java tag)

on opening the review page(s), those preferences are lost on re-opening (but a bit sporadic, occasionally not - didn't find anything obvious when or not it is happening).

Naturally, I consider that behaviour rather annoying, as it forces me to scroll to the bottom of the page, disable random, then search the tag I want, then scroll to the sort option then scroll to top ... you get it.

The question is one of two, depending on whether or not permanent config is already available:

- if so: how?
- if not: when will it be implemented (not doing so isn't an option, IMO)

Answer (score 2):

They shouldn't ever be lost. The system will always remember your preferences **unless** you visit the **suggested edits** tab, which resets them to the defaults (for some reason).

I thought I had opened a bug report about this before, but apparently I didn't. You should change this to a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) report, because that's more-or-less what it is.

**What I do:**

Whenever I visit the suggested edits tab, I open it in a new window (keeping the tab with all my preferences open on the side). Then, when I'm done reviewing suggested edits, I close that window and simply re-click the same tab in the previous window to re-apply my preferences I had before (they'll be in the link when you click the tab).

Comment: ahh ... yeah, that could be :-) updated the tags. Your hack probably works, but ... I don't like too many open windows/tabs ;-) Thanks anyway.

Comment: Don't accept an answer if you're going to change the question to a bug report... @kleo

Comment: @CodyGray oookay ... probably should read the faq here ;-) Done: couldn't find anything about not accepting-if-bug. Hmmm ..

Comment: If you accept an answer, the question appears to be resolved. Since you're changing the question to something else (a bug report) and therefore hoping to attract attention of those who might be able to fix the bug (or tell you why it's not a bug), you should probably not accept an answer. It's not in the FAQ, it's just common sense.

Comment: @CodyGray guilty of formulating the question not clearly: my mind meant "is this a bug and how to report it?" while my fingers typed "when will it be solved" - and my mind accepted this answer :-)