# Is it possible to remember disabled random ordering when reviewing?

Tags: discussion, review, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Review tools: how to configure preferences permanently?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123952/review-tools-how-to-configure-preferences-permanently)

When reviewing questions or answers, sometimes the content presented to me has a random ordering. At the bottom of the page I can usually either select more random content, or decide to disable the random ordering.

I personally don't like the random ordering, so I disable it. However, often when I return after a couple of hours or the next day, I'm back to random ordering. It seems to me this setting is not remembered. (This is on the same system, no deletion of history or clearing of cache.)

Is that indeed the case? Or am I missing some obvious preference setting somewhere?

<sub>I don't report this as either a bug or feature request yet, because I have a suspicion the problem might be me.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "disable random ordering" link just adds a additional query string parameter:

> [https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts?s=1&pagesize=30&filter=day**&no-random=1**](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts?s=1&pagesize=30&filter=day&no-random=1)

Looks like the system does not save it anywhere - if that flag is there it doesn't use the random ordering if there is no such flag and more than X items (100?) it will take 30 random items.

So feature request asking to store your last selection is a good idea in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for that confirmation. I'll make it a separate feature request then (rather than turning this into one).