# Remember last selected sorting option for review content

Tags: feature-request, review, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Review tools: how to configure preferences permanently?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123952/review-tools-how-to-configure-preferences-permanently)

In [an earlier question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137986/is-it-possible-to-remember-disabled-random-ordering-when-reviewing) I asked whether or not the ordering of content within the review panel could be remembered.

The answer to this was:

> The "disable random ordering" link just add additional query string parameter:
>   [https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts?s=1&pagesize=30&filter=day**&no-random=1**](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts?s=1&pagesize=30&filter=day&no-random=1)
>   Looks like the system does not save it anywhere

Therefore my feature request is simple:

Could we please store the last selected option (random ordering/no random ordering) for the content in the review panel?

It makes sense to me that when I select an option, I would like to keep this selected until I explicitly select otherwise.

Comment: Can this be implemented with HTML5 localStorage?

Comment: @nhahtdh I hope that's not a question for me, because I have no clue. :)

Comment: @Bart: Not for you particularly. I also don't know enough about HTML5 to be ascertain about it.