# Can the review preferences be saved?

Tags: bug, review, usability

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Review tools: how to configure preferences permanently?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123952/review-tools-how-to-configure-preferences-permanently)

I like the new [Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/) that is in Beta.  However, I have noticed that it doesn't seem to remember my review preferences like the old system did.

If I go to [Review Late answers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers?s=1&pagesize=15&filter=month) for the Month, it automatically defaults back to the 30 random posts, even though the last time I disabled that.

[image]

It also reverts back to 15 posts per page, even if I had selected 50 posts per page the last time.

[image]

Is this just something with the new review in Beta?  I never had this issue with the old review system.

Comment: @jadarnel27 I don't know if it is a dup because this feature was working with the old review system but does not appear to be working with the new system

Comment: @bluefeet: If you follow the duplicate link on that question, the feature had some bugs in it that caused your settings to be forgotten. This is probably just another one to add. But those other panels will eventually be converted to the new system, so this feature has no merit as it won'y exist in the future. Why should they care?