# Default sort order for answers does not stick

Tags: bug, sorting

There have been lots of questions about the sort order for answers on questions, but the most recent relevant ones seem to be from at least four or five years ago and are possibly not relevant anymore.

[This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123983/256878) from 2012 says that the sort order should not be lost, but that does not seem to be the case for me.

On sites where I have never changed the sorting order for answers on questions, the default order – by votes – is always adhered to. This is what I want.

On sites where, at some point in the past, I have changed the sort order, that sort order stubbornly remains in place, no matter how many times I reset it to the default or explicitly select votes. For example, whenever I navigate to a question on Stack Overflow (where at some point I apparently selected ‘newest first’ for some reason), the answers are ordered by ‘newest first’:

[image]

If I select a different sort order or click on “Reset to default”, the issue is fixed for the question I’m currently viewing, but as soon as I navigate away from the page and subsequently open the question (or a different one), even if it’s directly by clicking a link on the correctly sorted page, it goes right back to ‘newest first’.

If I view a question on a site that has the correct sort order (i.e., where I’ve never before changed it away from the ‘by votes’ option) and change it to one of the other types, the change is applied and sticks permanently. But if I change it back to ‘by votes’ or reset to default, that doesn’t stick – it goes back to the previously selected option.

What gives?

<sup>This is all on Safari 17.2 running on macOS Ventura 13.6 on a 13” M1 MacBook Pro (2020)</sup>

Comment: I have the same problems in one of the browsers I'm using (Safari on macOS) - I assume it's due to Adblock or Ghostery but I haven't found time to dig deeper.

Comment: @Glorfindel Ah, good point – I do indeed use Safari on macOS, and I do have AdBlock Plus installed (though not Ghostery). Testing a bit more, it seems my conditioning was actually not quite right either: it worked as described above on [linguistics.se] earlier tonight, but when I try now on [math.se] (where I’d never changed it before), nothing sticks at all – it just stays at the default, no matter which option I choose. So perhaps something about when a cookie was originally set?

Comment: I believe that in the past they used the Redis cache to store this settings, so it wasn't affected by cookies, and changed it as part of [Unpinning the accepted answer from the top of the list of answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369568/unpinning-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top-of-the-list-of-answers) to store it in a cookie. If I'll find more details I'll post it as answer.